# Things need to be hidden when the page loads

Tags: javascript

I've been slowly learning javascript and finally got my hide/show onClick working. When the page loads the content you see from the click needs to be hidden. How do I do this? Here is what I have now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head> 
</head> 
<body> 
<a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('adiv'))">click here</a> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function hideshow(which){ if (!document.getElementById) 
return if (which.style.display=="block") which.style.display="none" else which.style.display="block" } 
</script> 
<div id="adiv" style="display: block">This is what wil appear onClick</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'd recommend using jQuery as opposed to writing your own JavaScript.

Comment: try on http://jsfiddle.net/ , it will help you to learn....answer's keyword is onload of body or document ready .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the adiv style to `display: none`?

Comment: If it worked, then you may want to mark this as the accepted answer. Unless there was a better answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="adiv" style="display: none">This is what wil appear onClick</div>
```

just hide the element with css.

Answer (score 0):

And the error you are getting is:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if`

Remember to always end your statements with a **semi-colon;**

To correct your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head> 
</head> 
<body> 
<a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('adiv'))">click here</a> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function hideshow(which){ if (!document.getElementById) 
return; if (which.style.display=="block") which.style.display="none"; else which.style.display="block" } 
</script> 
<div id="adiv" style="display: block">This is what wil appear onClick</div>
</body>
```

It's also a good thing to use frameworks just like [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) so you don't need to start from scratch.

If you wish to hide `"adiv"` from the beginning, you should change `"display: block"` to `"display: none"`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function hideshow(which){ 
 return (which.style.display=="block")?
           which.style.display="none" : which.style.display="block" 
}
```